# "No installed OS" while trying to set up dual-boot with Windows 8.1

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 13.10, windows-8

I upgraded to Windows 8.1 and now I'm trying to dual-boot with Ubuntu 13.10.

When the install routine gets to the *what to do* part, it says "No recognisable OS found".

I am hesitant to continue manually because I don't want Ubuntu to remove the ability to boot into Windows (...in case I require this in the future).

Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your PC might be having fake raid drivers or GPT partitioning.. Check the BIOS and disable the option "Intel Rapid Start" & Intel Rapid Storage. Then again boot into USB with ubuntu and install gparted via software center and check the partitions showing up.

Then I think you can **delete the raid drivers** by `sudo dmraid -rE`

Now fire up the installation and it should find the installed OS.

Comment: 13.04 recognises Windows 8.1 without changing anything, 13.10 does not - it must be something missing in 13.10....